# Proof of existance of Eulerian cycle in directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

### Claim

A directed graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has equal in degree and out degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single strongly connected component.

I was looking for this proof in the Internet, but all i have found are the proofs for undirected graphs. I would be glad, if someone can give a link or name of the book, where i can find proof for this claim.

Comment: Check out the book *Digraphs* (2nd edition) by Bang-Jensen and Gutin: page 23, theorem 1.7.2 "Euler's theorem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages 5-8 of [Sascha Wolff](http://www1.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/en/staff/wolff_alexander)’s Lecture #1 “[Round Trips](http://www.electronics.lnu.edu.ua/fileadmin/konferences/kursmatem/graphtheory/agt-lecture01-roundtrips-druckversion.pdf)” from his last-year block-course “Algorithmic Graph Theory” contain an illustrated proof both for undirected and directed case.

Comment: link is now dead :(