# Eulerian Path In Directed Graph using SCC

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, eulerian-path

I read in geeks for geeks that we need to find out two things to know whether a digraph has eulerian circuit or not, they are:
 1. All vertices must belong to a single SCC.
 2. In and out degrees of each vertex should be the same.
My doubt is that why do we even need to find step 1, I am able to do it using only step 2 only, given the graph has only one connected component. Please help.
[GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euler-circuit-directed-graph/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011980/proof-of-existance-of-eulerian-cycle-in-directed-graph?rq=1) Alex Ravsky gives a [link to a proof](http://www.electronics.lnu.edu.ua/fileadmin/konferences/kursmatem/graphtheory/agt-lecture01-roundtrips-druckversion.pdf) (pages 5-8) and indeed it says:

"Let G be a directed and weakly connected graph. Then:
G Eulerian"

The fact that all vertices must belong to a single SCC isn't wrong of course, but it's nonsensical to include it imo as it follows from the following two conditions:

1. All vertices must belong to a single WCC.
2. In and out degrees of each vertex should be the same.